# How do I create a file name for my email attachment?

Tags: shell-script, cat, mailx, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux and am creating a bash script.  I'm tryhing to email an attachment and am having success with

```
(cat $TFILE1; uuencode $output_file $output_file) | mailx -s "$subject" "$to_email"
```

However the issue I'm having is taht the attachment is showing up (at least in Gmail) with the name "noname".  Is there a way I can make the attachment show up with the same name as the "$output_file" variable?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that `mail`/`mailx` have issues with attachments. 
Try using `mutt` instead, it handles attachments very well and should keep the filename intact.

```
mutt -a "$attachment_file" -s "$subject" -- "$to_email" < "$TFILE1"
```

where `"$TFILE1"` is the body of the mail message. Replace it with `/dev/null` if all you care to send is the attachment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I have the body of hte email in a file stored in the variable "$TFILE1".  How would I incorporate that into what you ahve above?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer.

Comment: The `cat` in backticks is ugly and brittle, and will flatten all whitespace. You want simply `<"$TFILE1"` there.

Comment: There are many versions of `mailx`, some of which support an `-a` option to attach a file.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, corrected and +1 to your comment.

Comment: I ran the above command but I got two attachments --
- one was just called "1.txtt," which contained the body of my email as an attachment and the other was the actual one I wanted as the attachment. 
 However, I'm souring on mutt since Gmail won't accept emails from mutt --
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172666/gmail-blocking-mutt

Answer (score 0):

`mpack` sets the attachment name equal to the input file name. So, for example (`-a` for attachment instead of inline; `-s` to set the subject; `-c` to set the MIME type; `1.png` is the file to attach; `anthony@localhost` is the email address to send to):

```
mpack -a -s 'test mpack' -c image/png 1.png anthony@localhost
```

sends me an email with `1.png` attached, with a file name:

```
Content-Type: image/png; name="1.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1.png"
Content-MD5: EGqHjkvvXXcaO+41lBN2uA==
```

So you just need to name your file correctly, then use `mpack`.

Another option, if you want complete control over the message, is `mime-construct`.

Comment: `mpack` once was fairly ubiquitous, but its last release was in 2003. It's a good utility to have, but you are unlikely to find it installed out of the box many places these days.

Comment: @tripleee indeed, same goes for `mime-construct`. But OP didn't say it needs to run everywhere, sounds like just on boxes he controls. So he can install it.

Comment: I tried "sudo yum install mpack" on my Amazon Linux system but got the error "No package mpack available.".

Comment: @Dave you can grab the source from ftp://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/ and compile it, or better yet grab the Debian source which has had more recent maintenance: https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/mpack rpmfind.net also finds a packaged version, but I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Yeah, I"m pretty sure mpack doesn't work with Amazon Linux.  When I downloaded teh source, I was able to ./configure, but running make resulted in an "make: *** [unixos.o] Error 1" error.

Comment: @Dave I'd try the Debian sources, they have a patch that looks to modernize the C syntax. Also, if you'd like help with the error, feel free to post a question (or of course use on of the other folk's answers).

Answer (score 0):

`uuencode` is a remnant from the early 1990s and should be avoided in favor of proper MIME tools if at all possible.

Unfortunately, there is still no *de facto* standard simple Unix command-line utility for sending MIME messages, though `mutt` comes close (but it's still primarily an interactive program, and thus includes a fair amount of bloat if all you need is to submit a message to your MTA from a script).

With modern scripting languages, a tool to send a multipart message with an inline text body part with a binary attachment is just a few lines of code. In bare shell script, the code is a bit bulkier; but the real challenge is often to know enough about MIME to be able to pull it off correctly. Briefly, you need to understand the overall structure of a MIME message and how to encode the body part type you want to use.

```
( printf 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n' "$sender" "$recipient" "$subject"
   printf 'Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foooobar"\n'
   printf '\n--foooobar\n\n'
   cat "$TFILE1"
   printf '\n--foooobar\nContent-type: application/octet-stream; name="%s"\n' "${output_file##*/}"
   printf 'Content-transfer-encoding: base64\n\n'
   base64 "$output_file"
   printf '\n--foooobar--\n' ) |
sendmail -t
```

This should work for basic 7-bit US-ASCII text; if you need 8-bit text, especially in the headers, there are a number of additional twists (RFC 2047 for human-readable text, RFC 2231 for file names and the like) at which point you'll really want to switch to a language which encapsulates these details so you don't have to understand them or worry about them.

Apart from the dependency on `base64` and `sendmail` for the actual submission, this is pure builtins and very basic shell utilities.  The parameter expansion `${output_file##*/}` should work with recent shells to remove everything through the final slash, though if you are on a really old one, you might want to use `basename` instead.

Comment: Not where I can test this right now - I'll probably update once I get a chance to spot typos etc. Bug reports welcome.

Comment: Updated now.  Bug reports still welcome.