# gmail sendgmail configuration for git send-email

Tags: git, gmail, golang

[From May 30, 2022](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255):

> Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

This is a problem for various applications including [`git send-email`](https://lore.kernel.org/git/d93a3024-ba8d-3469-2dba-2e0032334232@gmail.com/). [`sendgmail`](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/tree/master/go/sendgmail) is tool from Google written in go which allows to use OAuth2 credentials.

Using `sendgmail` requires certain [configuration in Google Cloud](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/tree/master/go/sendgmail#obtaining-oauth2-credentials-for-yourself), download JSON with configuration and rename to `~/.sendgmail.json` and then run once:

```
$ GOPATH/bin/sendgmail -sender=USERNAME@gmail.com -setup

1. Ensure that you are logged in as USERNAME@gmail.com in your browser.

2. Open the following link and authorise sendgmail:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...

3. Enter the authorisation code:
```

My `~/.sendgmail.json` contains `redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]`, therefore clicked website is redirected to localhost (no webserver is on my machine) and I don't get the authorisation code. Could anybody explain what exactly to do in Google Cloud setup to get it working?

Comment: Your information may be incomplete. From the link you referenced: `If "Less secure app access" is turned off for your account, you can turn it back on. We recommend switching to more secure apps instead.`  I still use gmail as an smtp server. Google complains about it sometimes, but as long as you use it regularly, it seems to work for me

Comment: Really it does not work for me: `5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials`.

Comment: Ach! You're correct - they've disabled it completely. Bummer... spammers have killed email. You've no access unless you "affiliate" with a big tech company, and now it seems even that is compromised. I used to run my own SMTP server, but gave it up years ago b/c so much of my outgoing mail never reached its destination. Hope you find an answer!

Comment: If you turn 2FA on, then you'll have the option to generate an app-specific password, which you can use instead of a password along with your regular username.

Comment: @bk2204 Thanks, also noticed (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172666/gmail-blocking-mutt/194247#194247), but I'd prefer to avoid 2FA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup the Workspace** by following [these steps.](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project)

**Enable the Gmail API** on the project.

**Setup the OAuth Consent Page.**

- I'm not sure if you can get past not having an authorized domain. I included one I own (and use for a different Google OAuth workflow)
- Ensure the Gmail API ../auth/gmail.send scope is allowed, nothing else seems required.
- Include yourself as a registered test user.

**Create Credentials.**

- Type: OAuth Client ID
- Application Type: Desktop App (others may work, just following linked guidance)

**Install the sendgmail go package**: `go install github.com/CyCoreSystems/gmail-oauth/sendgmail@latest`

**Run the setup command** as you've included.

**Follow the instructions** to authenticate and be redirected to the non-functional page (due to the redirect_uri being localhost.)

The authorization code you need to enter in the prompt can be scraped from the URL for that non-functional redirect.

Here is a example of the URL, you'll need the value of `code` GET parameter (i.e. the entire string after `code=` and before `&scope`):

```
http://localhost/?state=state&code=foobarauthcode&scope=https://mail.google.com/
```

The tool doesn't seem to output anything after submitting the authorization code, however testing sending a patch file to myself was successful with:

```
git send-email --smtp-server=$GOPATH/bin/sendgmail --smtp-server-option=-sender=myemailaddress@gmail.com patch-test.diff
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I have "a valid workspace", that's the most difficult part. Yes, installing go it's ok, running commands in shell is ok, configuring git is ok. The problem is to understand workspace setup (i.e. understand google web UI setup).

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if you need further expansion

Comment: Thx, I'll test it tonight. So they expect I run some go software instead of just printing toat code on their web page, lol. I should have looked to parameters myself, thanks!

Comment: I see Gmail API: `API Enabled` and enabled myself as user. I don't have an authorized domain. It fails when sending: `Unable to initialize SMTP properly. Check config and use --smtp-debug. VALUES: server=~/go/bin/sendgmail encryption=tls hello=localhost.localdomain port=587 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email line 1684` :(.

Comment: Could you please add more info about authorized domain? (link)

Comment: I added you a credit as you spent time on it. But true is that `sendgmail`. I temporarily use another free mail service provider and seriously thinking about creating my own mail hosting.